# Flutter Wait for the Notifier's constructor to be initiated

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to display in a listView builder a list that I load when initializing my constructor.
This doesn't work right now because the listView runs before the constructor has finished loading my list.

How to do ?

**My Notifier:**

```
class TablesNotifier with ChangeNotifier {

  // Services
  // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
  final jsonSelectorService = locator<JsonSelectorService>();

  // Variables
  // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
  List<AltitudeModel> altitudes;

  // Constructor
  // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
  TablesNotifier(){
    _initialise();
  }

  // Initialisation
  // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
  Future _initialise() async{
    print('--- initialise');
    altitudes = await jsonSelectorService.altitudes();
  }
}
```

**My screen:**

```
class TableScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  final String title;
  TableScreen({Key key, @required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: _buildBody(context),
    );
  }
  
  Widget _buildBody(BuildContext context)
  {
    var _tableProvider = Provider.of<TablesNotifier>(context);
    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: _tableProvider.altitudes.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return ListTile(
          title: Text('${_tableProvider.altitudes[index]}'),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: If there are no altitudes, then show ```CircularProgressIndicator```, once you got the data then call ```notifyListener()``` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can copy paste run full code below 
I use 7 seconds delay to simulate `jsonSelectorService` 
Step 1: You can check `_tableProvider.altitudes == null` and return `CircularProgressIndicator()` or `ListView` 
Step 2: when `altitudes` data is ready call `notifyListeners()` 
code snippet

```
Future _initialise() async {
    print('--- initialise');
    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 7), () {});
    altitudes = [
      AltitudeModel(title: "1"),
      AltitudeModel(title: "2"),
      AltitudeModel(title: "3"),
      AltitudeModel(title: "4"),
      AltitudeModel(title: "5")
    ];

    notifyListeners();
  }
  
Widget _buildBody(BuildContext context) {
    var _tableProvider = Provider.of<TablesNotifier>(context);
    return _tableProvider.altitudes == null
        ? Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator())
        : ListView.builder(
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider(
      create: (context) => TablesNotifier(),
      builder: (context, child) => MaterialApp(
        home: TableScreen(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class AltitudeModel {
  String title;

  AltitudeModel({this.title});
}

class TablesNotifier with ChangeNotifier {
  // Services
  // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
  //final jsonSelectorService = locator<JsonSelectorService>();

  // Variables
  // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
  List<AltitudeModel> altitudes;

  // Constructor
  // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
  TablesNotifier() {
    _initialise();
  }

  // Initialisation
  // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
  Future _initialise() async {
    print('--- initialise');
    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 7), () {});
    altitudes = [
      AltitudeModel(title: "1"),
      AltitudeModel(title: "2"),
      AltitudeModel(title: "3"),
      AltitudeModel(title: "4"),
      AltitudeModel(title: "5")
    ];

    notifyListeners();
  }
}

class TableScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  final String title;
  TableScreen({Key key, @required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: _buildBody(context),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildBody(BuildContext context) {
    var _tableProvider = Provider.of<TablesNotifier>(context);
    return _tableProvider.altitudes == null
        ? Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator())
        : ListView.builder(
            itemCount: _tableProvider.altitudes.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return ListTile(
                title: Text('${_tableProvider.altitudes[index].title}'),
              );
            },
          );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your time and this very structured answer!

Answer (score 1):

The quickest way is to use a `FutureBuilder` to make sure the `altitudes` list is fully loaded before sending it to UI. You can do this:

```dart
Widget _buildBody(BuildContext context) {
    var _tableProvider = Provider.of<TablesNotifier>(context);
    return FutureBuilder<List<AltitudeModel>>(
        initialData: <AltitudeModel>[] // Here you can even set the initial data of your list
        future: _tableProvider.altitudes,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            return Container(child: Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()));
          }
          return ListView.builder(
            itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return ListTile(
                title: Text('${snapshot.data[index]}'),
              );
            },
          );
        }
    );
  }
```